# Looping out slots?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my vue template I have:

```
<ul>
    <li>slide a</li>
    <li>slide b</li>
    ....
</ul>
```

But I want to pass in each slide from the parent using a slot, so:

```
<carousel>
    <img src="abc.jpg">
    <img src="xyz.jpg">
</carousel>
```

But how can I loop out what is passed in to each `li`? So I want to end up with:

```
 <ul>
    <li><img src="abc.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="xyz.jpg"></li>
    ....
</ul>
```

Also I want to be able to pass in any dom element via the slot to the list element.

Comment: This is not easily achievable. You better force the user to use a `<carousel-item />`  component that u can customize. Otherwise you use simply `div` or `section` instead of a `ul` so that yuo do not depend on `ul + li` construction

Comment: If you really want to do it that way, your best bet is using `render` function instead of `template`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what you are trying to do? I think you need scoped slots and emitted events where the scoped slots will take in props that are computed based on the emitted events although not totally sure I understood the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael said, you can achieve this behavior via [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots-with-the-slot-scope-Attribute).

In your *carousel component*, the template will look like this :

```
<ul>
  // TODO : Add a :key with a unique identifier
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <slot name="item" :item="item">
      {{ item }}
    </template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And when using the component, you will do something like this :

```
<carousel :items="images">
  <img #item="{ src }" :src="src">
</carousel>
```

Depending on your `images` data, you may need to get the source from another property.